# CodeIgniter - Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with submitting a post using ajax post method. Its not giving me any error message it seems to post the request but the model isnt responding so it seems inserting the row in the database.

I'm not the best in jQuery / javascript but im hopelessly stuck and cant find anything somewhat related to my situation on stackoverflow.

**Controller: spelers.php**

```
public function historie()
{   
    if(isset($_SESSION['validated']))
    {  
        // Models 
        $this->Spelers_model->insertHistorie(); 
    } 
    else
    {
        redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**Model: spelers_model.php**

```
public function insertHistorie() 
{   
    // Variable     
    $spelerid = $this->input->post('spelerid');
$speler_id = $this->input->post('speler_id');
$speler_naam = $this->input->post('speler_naam');
$speler_slug = url_title($this->input->post('speler_naam'), 'dash', TRUE);
$sum = strtotime ('+$actie day' , strtotime ( $datum_ban )) ; 
$datum_unban = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , $sum );
$datum_ban = $this->input->post('datum_ban');
$actie = $this->input->post('actie');
$reden = $this->input->post('reden');
$bewijs = $this->input->post('bewijs');
$extrainfo = $this->input->post('extrainfo');
$kayako_ticket = $this->input->post('kayako_ticket');       
$moderator = $this->input->post('moderator');

// Query Historie DB
    $data = array(
    'spelerid' => $spelerid,
        'speler_id' => $speler_id,
        'speler_naam' => $speler_naam,
    'speler_slug' => $speler_slug,
    'datum_unban' => $datum_unban,
    'datum_ban' => $datum_ban,
        'actie' => $actie,
        'reden' => $reden,
        'bewijs' => $bewijs,
        'extrainfo' => $extrainfo,
        'kayako_ticket' => $kayako_ticket,
        'moderator' => $moderator
    );

$this->db->insert('speler_historie', $data);

if($datum_unban === '') {

}
else 
{
// Query Banlist DB
$data2 = array(
     'spelerid' => $spelerid,
     'speler_id' => $speler_id,
     'speler_naam' => $speler_naam,
     'speler_slug' => $speler_slug,
     'datum_unban' => $datum_unban,
     'datum_ban' => $datum_ban,
     'actie' => $actie,
     'reden' => $reden,
     'bewijs' => $bewijs,
     'extrainfo' => $extrainfo,
     'kayako_ticket' => $kayako_ticket,
         'moderator' => $moderator,
     'status' => '0'
);

$this->db->insert('banlist', $data2);
}
}
```

**View: view.php**

```
<!-- historie -->
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var 
            spelerid = $( "#spelerid" ),
            speler_id = $( "#speler_id" ),
            speler_naam = $( "#speler_naam" ),
            datum_ban = $( "#datum_ban" ),
            actie = $( "#actie" ),
            reden = $( "#reden" ),
            bewijs = $( "#bewijs" ),
            extrainfo = $( "#extrainfo" ),
            kayako_ticket = $( "#kayako_ticket" ),
            moderator = $( "#moderator" ),
            allFields = $( [] ).add( spelerid ).add( speler_id ).add( speler_naam ).add( datum_ban ).add( actie ).add( reden ).add( bewijs ).add( extrainfo ).add( kayako_ticket ).add ( moderator ),
            tips = $( ".validateTips" );

            function updateTips( t ) {
                tips
                    .text( t )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                    tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
                }, 500 );
            }

            function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
                if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    updateTips( "Kan geen lege " + n + " toevoegen." );
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 350,
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Toevoegen": function() {
                        var bValid = true;
                        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                        bValid = bValid && checkLength( bewijs, "Bewijs", 3, 1020 );
                        bValid = bValid && checkLength( kayako_ticket, "Kayako Ticket", 3, 1020 );

                        if ( bValid ) {

                            $.ajax({  
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/spelers/<?php echo $speler['slug']; ?>/historie",
                                data: {
                                    spelerid: $('#spelerid').val(),
                                    speler_id: $('#speler_id').val(),
                                    speler_naam: $('#speler_naam').val(),
                                    datum_ban: $('#datum_ban').val(),
                                    actie: $('#actie').val(),
                                    reden: $('#reden').val(),
                                    bewijs: $('#bewijs').val(),
                                    extrainfo: $('#extrainfo').val(),
                                    kayako_ticket: $('#kayako_ticket').val(),
                                    moderator: $('#moderator').val()
                                },
                                success: function(data){
                                    location.reload();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
              },
              close: function() {
                allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
              }
            });

            $( "#create-historie" )
                .click(function() {
                    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                });

        });
    </script>
            <?php
    $moderator = $_SESSION['username'];
    $datum_ban = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    ?>

    <div id="dialog-form" title="Ban <?php echo $speler['speler_naam']; ?> | Toevoegen">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <form>

            <table width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td width="15%"><?php echo form_label('Dagen: *', 'actie'); ?></td>
            <td width="50%">
            <?php echo form_dropdown('actie', $acties, NULL, 'id="actie" onchange="load_dropdown_content($(\'#actie\'), this.value)"'); ?>
            </td>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Reden: *', 'reden'); ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('reden', $redenen, NULL, 'id="reden" onchange="load_dropdown_content($(\'#reden\'), this.value)"'); ?>
            </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Extra Info: *', 'extrainfo'); ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('extrainfo', $extrainfos, NULL, 'id="extrainfo" onchange="load_dropdown_content($(\'#extrainfo\'), this.value)"'); ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Bewijs: *', 'bewijs'); ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bewijs" id="bewijs" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 300px; height: 15px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Kayako Ticket: *', 'kayako_ticket'); ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="kayako_ticket" id="kayako_ticket" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 100px; height: 15px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <!-- hidden -->
            <input type="hidden" name="spelerid" id="spelerid" value="<?php echo $speler['id']; ?>" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <input type="hidden" name="speler_id" id="speler_id" value="<?php echo $speler['speler_id']; ?>" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <input type="hidden" name="speler_naam" id="speler_naam" value="<?php echo $speler['speler_naam']; ?>" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <input type="hidden" name="datum_ban" id="datum_ban" value="<?php echo $datum_ban; ?>" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <input type="hidden" name="moderator" id="moderator" value="<?php echo $moderator; ?>" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <!-- /hidden -->
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
        <p class="validateTips">* Verplicht veld.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /historie -->
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should really use `$this->input->post('some_data');` instead of ` mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[])`

Comment: You said: 'The model isn't responsing'. Any debug? Are you sure that `if(isset($_SESSION['validated']))` return true?

Comment: can you put some debugging code at the top of your historie() function to see if it is being called? - perhaps var_dump($_SESSION['validated']) might be a good start. Also, what url does the ajax post to? I think the slug you have in between spelers/ and /historie might be causing a problem. Unless you are dealing with this in your routes.php config file.

Comment: hmm . @Steven4Hawkes first check whether it is calling the proper ajax url using firebug or something. And one more thing this is not right way to code in codeigniter . You have to get all the data on controller and pass it model for insertion. check any mvc docs.

Comment: @Guicara: Ive done the var_dump($_SESSION['validated']) and get return: boolean true.

Comment: So your Model is called. The problem is else where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the ajax url is not valid. You have built it as

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/spelers/<?php echo $speler['slug']; ?>/historie"
```

which will give something like

**yourdomain.com/index.php/spelers/your-slug/historie**

Codeigniter routing would try and route this to the *spelers* controller (which is fine) and then the *your-slug()* method (which is not fine as it probably doesn't exist.).

If you want to call the historie() method in your spelers controller, you need your url to come out something like this;

**yourdomain.com/index.php/spelers/historie**

If you want the slug to go in as another parameter, you need to either put it on the end of the ajax url, and access it via the uri->segment() method of the [URI class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html), or pass it in as a POSTed parameter in the data part of your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the example bellow:

**In controller**

```
public function historie()
{   
    if(isset($_SESSION['validated']))
    {  
        // Models 
        $this->Spelers_model->insertHistorie(); 
        echo array('error_code' => 0);
    } 
    else
    {
        echo array('error_code' => 1);
    }
}
```

**In view**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {},
    complete: function () {},
    url: "abc.php",
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // debug data
            if (data.error_code === 0){
                location.reload();
            } else {
                window.location.href="/login";
            }
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert('Fail ' + error);
    }
});
```